# Microsoft.VCLibs Visual Studio build error for ARM architecture

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, arm, visual-studio-2019, hololens

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.15) on Windows desktop. I need to build a UWP App or DLL plugin for ARM architecture platform, such as HoloLens2. It builds fine for x64 but not for ARM64. The error comes from Microsoft.VCLibs dependency.

> Error MSB3779 The processor architecture of the project being built
> "ARM" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs,
> Version=14.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
> architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
> through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
> supported by the SDK: "x86, x64".

I can't find a way to remove this dependency from my VS solution. I've tried to install the  Microsoft.VCLibs.arm64.14.00.Desktop.appx from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/libraries/c-runtime-packages-desktop-bridge . But I also got an error saying that I can't install this because my desktop is x64. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: This app's dependency,  and above dependency only support arm architecture, if you  want to install into your x64 platfrom. please install `Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx`  version.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT but I can't build and deploy for Hololens2, as it targets ARM architecture

Comment: You could build arm 64 package with vs within current x64 paltfrom.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT but then I got the above error saying `The processor architecture of the project being built "ARM" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=14.0"`

Comment: I tried build the project with arm64 architecture, it could work well in my side without above exception. can you share your current sdk version and your project's target and min version ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT do you Build UWP project with x64 PC? I am targeting UWP, SDK and min SDK version both are 10.0.19041.0

Comment: I build uwp project [arm 64 in pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N6AD.png).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT then probably Visual Studio related? I am using the latest version of VS2019 now, and it automatically searches for Microsoft.VCLibs dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245836/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-gameon67).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It builds fine for x64 but not for ARM64. The error comes from Microsoft.VCLibs dependency.

I have tested within my current VS2022, it could build arm64 successfully without dependency error. And it looks more related with VS, please try to repair it or install new VS2022 to repalce.